# How to move files to folders based on string left to a fixed separator string in each file name?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, move

For example I have a folder called:

> ```
> FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
> ```

And I have the files:

> ```
> FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CHK#123
> FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CHK#145
> ```

I want to make a batch to move all files automatically. I have this code from another post:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
pushd "C:\Folders\"
for %%a in (*) do (
    set fldr=%%~na
    set fldr=!fldr:~0,4!
    md "!fldr!"
    move "%%a" "!fldr!"
)
popd
pause
exit
```

But it creates a folder with the first four characters if the file has more than four characters.

What I want to do is that the batch file evaluates the file name, stops at separator string  `CHK#` and moves the file to the folder based on first and last name in file name left to  `CHK#`.

Comment: would you consider using a powershell script rather than a batch file?

Comment: Do the folders already exist, or do you have to create them (by the script)?

Comment: Powershell is ok too :) And yes, they usually exist but not all the time.

Comment: Given your example, `!fldr:~0,4!`, would be, `FIRS`!

Comment: If the folders exist in advance, I'd iterate though them and move matching files within: `for /D %%I in (*) do move "%%~nI*.*" "%%~I"`. If they do not exist, it becomes a bit more complicated, because you have to split the file names based on certain rules, which you need to define clearly (first name and last name do not contain spaces on their own, both are not empty, no middle name, etc.)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PowerShell solution using a RegEx to get the file name parts in front of `CHK#` by using
a [lookahead zerolength assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\01\SO_55462032.ps1

Pushd "C:\Folder"

Get-ChildItem *CHK#* -File | Where Name -match '^(.*)(?= CHK#)' | ForEach-Object {
   If(!(Test-Path $Matches[1])){New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $Matches[1]}
   $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Matches[1]
}
PopD
```

Sample output:

```
> tree /F
├───FirstName
│       FirstName CHK#654
│
├───FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
│       FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CHK#123
│       FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CHK#145
│
├───Firstname Middlename Lastname
│       Firstname Middlename Lastname CHK#987
│
└───Title Firstname MiddleName Lastname
        Title Firsname MiddleName Lastname CHK#159
```

Comment: Save with any name and `.ps1` extension, To run it in an open powershell window either supply a path,or if in current dir precede the name with `.\` other than cmd it won't execute from current dir without that.

Comment: Thank you mate! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Just saw that comment formatting mangled the text. I meant prepend the file name with dot backslash if in current folder.

Comment: If answers solve your question or you find them helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple batch file solution for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("C:\Folders\* CHK#*") do call :ProcessFile "%%I"
endlocal
goto :EOF

:ProcessFile
set "FileName=%~nx1"
set "CheckSum=%FileName:* CHK#= CHK#%"
call set "FolderName=%%FileName:%CheckSum%=%%"
md "%~dp1%FolderName%" 2>nul
move /Y %1 "%~dp1%FolderName%"
goto :EOF
```

The string after  `CHK#` must not have an equal sign or one or more percent signs.

The subroutine `ProcessFile` assigns with a string substitution the string part beginning from first occurrence of `CHK#` to end of file name to environment variable `CheckSum`.

One more string substitution is used to remove the checksum string from file name to get the folder name. This command line is double parsed by Windows command processor because of command `call` to replace on first parsing `%CheckSum%` by current value of environment variable `CheckSum` and replace both `%%` by just a single `%`. On second parsing the remaining `set "FolderName=%FileName: CHK#123=%"` is processed resulting in assigning to environment variable `FolderName` the string `FIRSTNAME LASTNAME` for the first file name example. See also [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?` and see also [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- `md /?`
- `move /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Answer (score 0):

One way to split the file name into parts is to use the space and `#` as delims
and check if the 3rd token is `CHK`

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\01\SO_55462032.cmd
@echo off  
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
pushd "C:\Folders\" 
for %%F in ("* * CHK#*") do for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=# " %%A in ("%%F") Do (   
    if "%%C"=="CHK" (
        if not Exist "%%A %%B" MD "%%A %%B"
        Move "%%F" "%%A %%B"
    ) else if "%%D"=="CHK" (
        if not Exist "%%A %%B %%C" MD "%%A %%B %%C"
        Move "%%F" "%%A %%B %%C"
    )

) 
popd 
pause 
exit /b
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_55462032.cmd
        1 Datei(en) verschoben.
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
> tree a:\ /F
├───FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
│       FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CHK#123
│       FIRSTNAME LASTNAME CHK#145
│
└───Firstname Middlename Lastname
        Firstname Middlename Lastname CHK#987
```

Comment: And what if there is a middle name?

Comment: Then your specification fell short, and I'll add an else and another if.

Comment: Ah its working, you are my hero! How can i edit it to be able to deal with names with only firstnames, and names longer than 3 part?

Comment: Well I kept the solution as simple as possible to match your **INITIAL** specs, while it is possible to add some more IFs and else I think a solution in PowerShell featuring full fledged Regular Expressions is more adequate, wait a minute for another answer.